# FFMPEG, Netbeans and C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, ffmpeg, mingw

I used to work on C++ project on Netbeans and I would like to use ffmpeg libraries / include files all the stuff inside my program. I don't know how to install ffmpeg in there and integrate it with Netbeans  have installed also the latest mingw? I have surfed the net for such a topic then I have found one but to be honest I understand a very little.

System info:

Windows 8 64bit
Netbeans 7.3 32.b
mingw 32bit
opencv 4.4 32.bit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows. but using netbeans on linux, this is what I did.

Right Click on the c++ project you are using ffmpeg with and Select "Properties".

In the popup window select "Build"->"C++ Compiler".

Under "General" edit "Include Directories" and add the directory to your ffmpeg source code

e.g "~/ffmpeg_source/ffmpeg",

after which select "Linker" under "Build" and under "Compilation Line" edit "Addition Options"

and add "$$(pkg-config --libs --cflags {{ffmpeg libraries your project depends on}})"

e.g "$$(pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat)" because my current project is using on libavformat.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks Bro I will try them except I didnt understand what do you mean by pkg config libs cflags , am pretty new here also want how do you include and use the ffmpeg stuff with your c++ code, is it the same thing as the command line as opening a console on the code or there is a special language for ffmpeg as the one we used in opencv as example (mat and etc...)..

Comment: pkg-config is tool that helps you include the libraries your project is depending on when building. To use ffmpeg with c++, you can use the system() call in your code or you can include ffmpeg in your code. You have to google how to do that on windows cos I don't know about that